# Docker Compose host path error with nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I've a error when I run `docker-compose up nginx` with my host path :

> ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\"/d/Sites/lfdwveille/app/config/docker/nginx.conf\\" to rootfs \\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/fce42187ef3ff6bcc0d5acf53a77d2218348a432063e2d5fe00b8ac945578f63\\" at \\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/fce42187ef3ff6bcc0d5acf53a77d2218348a432063e2d5fe00b8ac945578f63/etc/nginx/nginx.conf\\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\""
>
> : Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
>
> [31mERROR[0m: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

The folder url is correct :( I don't know why nginx don't want mount folder and I've no problem with PHP and MySQL.

My setup :

- **Windows**
- **docker-compose v1.9.0**
- **docker 1.12**

Error log :

> container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\"/d/Sites/lfdwveille/app/config/docker/nginx.conf\\" to rootfs \\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/fce42187ef3ff6bcc0d5acf53a77d2218348a432063e2d5fe00b8ac945578f63\\" at \\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/fce42187ef3ff6bcc0d5acf53a77d2218348a432063e2d5fe00b8ac945578f63/etc/nginx/nginx.conf\\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\""

Anyone have idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker compose - share volume Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995626/docker-compose-share-volume-nginx)

Comment: Can you share your docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Docker Machine on Windows, docker has limited access to your Windows filesystem. By default Docker Machine tries to auto-share your C:\Users (Windows) directory.

[Docker compose - share volume Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995626/docker-compose-share-volume-nginx/35996896#35996896)