# How can I get nginx alpine to see a directory on the C drive using Docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm working with nginx and Docker for the first time. I have an app that reads/writes to a directory on the file system. I'm trying to setup a dev environment using Docker and I need the nginx image to be able to know this path exists on my dev machine so that it can read from and write to it. Is there anyway to configure this within my docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Use volumes - [docker-compose nginx volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995626/docker-compose-share-volume-nginx)

Comment: Are you checking whether the current system is a development or production in the docker container?